# Image shadow css3

Tags: html, css

[image]

This is the top of the sketch of my website, I've done this in a HTML editor. 
The circle we can see in the image is my logo, it's an image with alpha color background.
Shadows, borders, etc are working perfectly even in IE.
Now I'm trying to do something similar with HTML5 and CSS3 but I'm having lots of problems with image shadows and borders.
box-shadow doesn't work because it's a square image (remember it's a image with alpha color background)
The last thing I've found for image shadow is filter: drop-shadow. In theory it should work on  all browsers but it's only working with chrome.
On the other hand, i can't get a border like the one on the picture. As you know, my logo is a image with alpha color background and it always makes a square border.

Can anybody give me some help. I would appreciate it. Thanxs

---

After using the solution Lloan Alas gave me it's working perfectly but not on mobile phone
I use dolphin browser and this is what i get:
[image: mobil phone]
This is my code: css:
    #logo { 
    margin-top: -100px;
    height: 188px; 
    width: 300px;
    background-image: url("../imagenes/logo.png"); 
    border: 5px solid white; 
    border-radius: 50% ;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 15px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 15px #000; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 15px #000; 
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 10px 15px #000; 
    -o-box-shadow: 0 10px 15px #000; 
    -khtml-box-shadow: 0 10px 15px #000; 
}
html:
    <div id="logo"></div>

Comment: Could you make your question a bit clearer? It’s a bit of a ramble at the moment.

Comment: I think what he means is that his image has an elliptical form with a transparent background. When he adds a border to the image, the border is drawn around the edge of the image (which is a square).

Comment: Yeh, when i say alpha background i mean transparent. Anyway Lloan Alas' answer is working for me though it's not what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a live demo - Let me know if it helps!  [LIVE DEMO JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ixakiq/2/)

Compatible with IE 9-10, Firefox, Safari and Opera. (Supposedly)

Comment: This is not what i was looking for but it's working. Thanxs a lot.

Comment: What browser is the MP using and can you perhaps show an image of what you're seeing? (screenshot)

Answer (score 1):

I don't get very well what are you looking for, but if you want to add a shadow to that ellipse what you need is `box-shadow`, as you know 
The use is:

```
box-shadow: horizontal-shadow-position v-shadow-pos blur spread color inset;
```

where you can ommit a property but you cannot change its order.

So for instance your shadow will be something like

```
box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px 2px #666;
```

because it's **not** inset.

In addition, to be able to use it in more browsers, you will need the browser prefix, such as

```
box-shadow:         3px 3px 8px 2px #666; /*Firefox (and new versions of Opera)*/
-o-box-shadow:      3px 3px 8px 2px #666; /*Opera*/
-ms-box-shadow:     3px 3px 8px 2px #666; /*Internet Explorer*/
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px 2px #666; /*Webkit: Safari, Chrome, Chromium...*/
```

Also, remember that the `alpha-filter` you mentioned is just the equivalent to `opacity` property for **Firefox, Chrome, Opera, ...**

Comment: Please do not refer to W3Schools as a reference. It contains information that is outdated. For further clarification please visit the following link [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com/)

Comment: My logo is a image with alpha color background, so it makes a square shadow.

Comment: Excuse me, Lloan; reference removed. In any case, I just referenced W3 but I wrote everything from memory. This will be the last time ever I reference W3. Cheers